# finding multiple words in every sentence with regex

Tags: regex, visual-studio

In Visual Studio 2017 I would like to find all occurences of

```
.start (dot start)
```

and

```
->start (arrow start)
```

but no luck getting it to work.

I've tried

```
(.)|(->)start 
(\.)|(->)start
(.)(->)start 
(\.)(->)start
```

How do you find multiple words attached to another word?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `(.)|(->)start` does not work because it matches any char (`(.)`) or (`|`) a `->start`. The `(\.)|(->)start` matches a literal `.` or `->start`. The `(.)(->)start` matches any char followed with `->start`. The `(\.)(->)start` matches a dot followed with `->start`.

To match a dot or `->` followed with `start` use

```
(?:\.|->)start
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3A%5C.%7C-%3E%29start&i=.start%0D%0A-%3Estart).

**Details**

- `(?:\.|->)` - a non-capturing group matching 1 or the 2 alternatives:

  - `\.` - a literal dot
  - `->` - a `->` substring
- `start` -  a literal substring.

To match it as a whole word, you may use variations of the pattern:

```
 (?:\.|->)start\b
```

or

```
\B(?:\.|->)start\b
```

Where `\b` will force the match at the word boundary (the next char should be either a non-word char (symbol, whitespace, punctuation), or end of string, and `\B` requires a non-word char or start of string before the `.` or `-`.